# How to bind the close event for this script jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i need to reload the parent page when close button clicked on modal dialog.
my code is:

```
//customer edit start
 $( ".modal-customeredit" ).click(function() {
        var myGroupId = $(this).attr('data-id'); // data-id


           $.post("sample.php",
    {
      name:myGroupId,

    },
    function(data,status){

    });
                  $( "#modal-customeredit" ).dialog({
     modal: true,
     minWidth: 700,
     minHeight: 200,
     dialogClass: "modal-dialog",
     show: "fadeIn"




          });

       $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('bg-black opacity-60');


 });
```

I tried for close button as/

```
 $( ".ui-dialog-titlebar-close" ).click(function() {
      window.location.reload(true);
 });
```

on below also tried inside.Nothing works.Can anybody help me.Thanks.

Comment: are you using iframe??

Comment: What about event delegation?

Comment: No its a modal window.with close button.@dhaval can you be clear!

Comment: Looks like you're using some framework for the modals. Are you? If so, which one(s)? Have you also checked that the your close function runs after clicking the button?

Comment: can you give link to your page or example at jsbin?

Comment: yes i think.I tried its not running @zhihao

Comment: Yea sure ll make one @VasilVanchuk

Answer (score 1):

You can use native `create` event of dialogue to bind close button click. Like this:

```
$( "#modal-customeredit" ).dialog({
 modal: true,
 minWidth: 700,
 minHeight: 200,
 dialogClass: "modal-dialog",
 show: "fadeIn",
 create: function() {
        $(this).closest('div.ui-dialog')
               .find('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')
               .click(function(e) {
                   window.location.reload(true);
                   e.preventDefault();
               });}
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vvjj8/67/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use window property , to get access to main page from iframe

> top   Returns the topmost browser window

can you give link to your page or example at jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

Elements that are added to the `DOM` at runtime requires event delegation as your popup is generated using model (jQuery UI) 
You can execute a click event of close button by doing this:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.ui-dialog-titlebar-close',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // To prevent default dialog close action
      window.location.reload(true);
});
```

See the API documentation for [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

May be this will fix. But i think `close()` of model popup is already defined in `UI`. You may prevent the default action.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Cheers!